# Finding a generating function for the set of all integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I know that integers can be partitioned into the different ways to get that integer. For example:

$$4 = 3+1 = 2+2 = 2+1+1 = 1+1+1+1$$

can be written as

$$(4),(3, 1),(2, 2),(2, 1, 1),  (1, 1, 1, 1)$$

We can then define the size of a partition

$$λ = (λ_1, \ldots, λ_k)$$

to be

$$\sum λ_i$$ (so partitions of $n$ have size $n$)

How can I find a generating function for the set of all integer partitions?

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Generating_function).

Comment: You can also take a look at [this](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mhaiman/math172-spring10/partitions.pdf).

Comment: Notice that "a generating function for the *set*..." doesn't make as much sense as the identified duplicate.  A generating function connects a power series expansion with certain coefficients, presumably (unrestricted) *partition numbers* in your problem.